# Installing Azure Functions Core Tools on Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, azure-functions, iot, azure-functions-core-tools

I am having difficulty installing the Azure Functions Core Tools on a Raspberry Pi.  To give some context, I am working on a project that exclusively uses a Raspberry Pi computer paired with a Chromebook to learn and practice 3 main technologies (simple web app development w/ Django, IoT programming using [MS IoT for Beginners](https://github.com/microsoft/IoT-For-Beginners), and Progressive Web App development - again using Django).  We are basically using the Chromebook as a terminal for the Raspberry Pi.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed on the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4.  I am following these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?WT.mc_id=academic-17441-jabenn&tabs=v4%2Clinux%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash) to install the Azure Functions Core Tools.  Under the "Install the Azure Functions Core Tools" section, I am able to follow the first 4 steps and then when it comes to step 5 - "sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools-4", I am getting the following error:

E: Unable to locate package azure-functions-core-tools-4

I have tried the following thus far:

1. I have successfully installed Azure CLI using "pip install azure-cli", which is required for Azure Functions Core Tools.
2. Manually changed the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list FROM:

deb [arch=**amd64**] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy main

TO: deb [arch=**arm64**] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy main

3. Tried installing and using Ubuntu's last LTS release 20.04 - focal

Attempts 2 and 3 from above yielded the same error message of:

E: Unable to locate package azure-functions-core-tools-4

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could try the npm version https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools (It has 1,3+4)

Comment: Hi @Tyeth - thanks for the suggestion. I did try to use npm to install the Azure Functions Core Tools. I don't remember the exact error I received, but couldn't get it to work.